# restrict height of collapsed accordion segment Bootstrap 5 Vue3

Tags: vue.js, sass, bootstrap-5

I am building a web app with Vue3 and bootstrap 5. But I think this issue only concerns bootstrap. What I want to do is to restrict the height of the collapsed accordion segment, so it does not kick the other segments too far down when its content is long.

What I tried is to add max-height and overflow: auto to the class .collapsing and I already added "collapsing" to the classes of the accordion but then the accordion scrolls to the height and after a second jumps to full unfolding. In the node_modules bootstrap folder, I looked into the _accordion.scss and changed "overflow-anchor" to auto and nothing changed.

```
.collapsing {
  max-height: 100px !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```

On this example file i just took the accordion example from [bootstrap(under "Flush")](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/) so my vue file looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
        <button
          class="accordion-button collapsed"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="flush-collapseOne"
        >
          Accordion Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div
        id="flush-collapseOne"
        class="accordion-collapse collapse"
        aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne"
        data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample"
      >
        <div class="accordion-body">
          Placeholder<br />this must be long <br />this must be long <br />this
          must be long <br />this must be long <br />this must be long
          <br />this must be long <br />this must be long <br />this must be
          long <br />this must be long(thats what she said) <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
        <button
          class="accordion-button collapsed"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo"
        >
          Accordion Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div
        id="flush-collapseTwo"
        class="accordion-collapse collapse"
        aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo"
        data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample"
      >
        <div class="accordion-body">
          Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to
          demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the
          second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with
          some actual content.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "stackoverflowquestion",
};
</script>

<style>
.collapsing {
  max-height: 100px !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
}
</style>
```

any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
You gotta put the class in the accordion-body.
So at first define a class like

```
.restrict-collapsing {
  max-height: 100px !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```

then call it within the same bracket as accordion-body

> ```
> <div class="accordion-body restrict_collapsing">
>           Placeholder<br />this must be long <br />this must be long <br />this
>           must be long <br />this must be long <br />this must be long
>           <br />this must be long <br />this must be long <br />this must be
>           long <br />this must be long(thats what she said) <br />
>         </div>
> ```